# Github webhook with Jenkins - 'We couldn’t deliver this payload: failed to connect to host'

Tags: http, github, kubernetes, jenkins, curl

I am using Github plugin in Jenkins.
My jenkins runs on K8S pod using Kubernets plugin.

Trying to trigger a push event by pushing to my branch fails on Github side.
`We couldn’t deliver this payload: failed to connect to host`

I'm able to reach [www.github.com](http://www.github.com) within the pod, and even using organization folder (scanning the github organization) gives me all the branches and webhook registers on github automatically using www..com/github-webhook

I'm using access token of an account with Admin permissions in the repo in Github.

Triggering manual hook from Jenkins gives me in the Jenkins logs -
`Created hook https://api.github.com/repos/xxx-xxx/xxx-xxx/hooks/404803105 (events: [PULL_REQUEST, PUSH, REPOSITORY])`

But when I'm doing build, nothing shows in [www.jenkins.com/logs..](http://www.jenkins.com/logs..).
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it looks like you have some notwork related problem.
Seems that your `Jenkins` instance is not reachable from internet and that is why `GitHub` which is public service is not able to send payload to your host.
Please make sure that at least this endpoint `$JENKINS_BASE_URL/github-webhook/` is exposed to internet so it can receive trigger message.